# Autocomplete with REST API works locally but not on web server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a REST API that pulls data which needs to be accessible from an auto-completing search box in a web application. This seems to be working completely fine locally, however when I push this to the production environment the autocomplete doesn't work.

After some testing I have worked out that the `success` method of the AJAX request is simply not firing when running on the server. This doesn't make sense to me since it works locally on my machine.

Other parts of the API are working completely fine online, it's just the autocomplete that is not working as intended.

I know that the request is firing properly because when I dump the data before it gets returned back to AJAX everything is present. However trying to do anything in the `success` method just results in nothing.

```js
$("#origin").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'post',
      url: "/journey_query/get_origin_stations",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        'origin': origin_box
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(request);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(data['places'][0]['place']);

        $('#origin-stations').removeClass("is-hidden");
        jQuery.each(data['places'], function(i, val) {
          console.log(val['place']['name']);
          $(".origin-stations").append("<a class='origin-place' href='#'><li>" + val['place']['name'] + "</li></a>");
        });

        $('#origin-field').removeClass("is-loading");
      },
      fail: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
        alert("failure")
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you made any steps to debug this? Check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the console is not reporting any errors

Comment: in The network tab, you can see the server response.

Comment: Are you sure? If the `success` method is not being executed it implies that a server-side error is occuring as you're not getting a 200 OK response. Check the actual status of the request in the network tab of dev tools

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan just had a look at this and i'm getting a 200 OK response on the network tab

Comment: In which case the problem could be that the response is not valid JSON and could not be deserialised correctly. Can you post the responseText in the question

Comment: Are the `console.log()` calls being shown?

Comment: the console.log() calls are not showing so i'm struggling to get a response. seems strange for this to only work locally. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: can you tell me what is the result of console.log(data);

Comment: @NegiRox this outputs nothing as it appears the success is not firing when im getting a 200 OK response

Comment: is your php code is returning a value properly? try directly ajax with your API

Comment: the php code returns the values, they're just not being passed back to the AJAX success method @NegiRox